# How to generate an APK (NOT APKS ) from AAB using bundletool?

Tags: android, apk, android-build, android-bundle, android-app-bundle

I'm looking for a solution to generate an APK from Android App Bundle which will help me to share the App for internal testing rather publishing on Google Play Beta Testing.

Is there a way or a command using [bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool)?

Comment: have you installed bundletool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the best option is to use  [**Internal App Sharing**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479) that allows to test easily your App Bundles and APKs, including debug builds:

> With internal app sharing, you can quickly share an app bundle or APK with your internal team and testers by uploading an APK or app bundle on the [internal app sharing upload page](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/internalappsharing/).

If you want to go the bundletool route, you need to generate an universal apk. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907000/118862) on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We are working on multiple projects and sharing APKs (using CI/CD) for internal testing so we don't publish the app until the customer provides the developer account. I'm looking for a solution just to share the APKS or AAB which should work as same as APK does.

Answer (score 4):

pfmaggi mentioned Internal App Sharing, which is indeed the best way to test exactly what users will get.

An alternative, which isn't as accurate and doesn't always work in some edge cases, is building a universal APK by passing the flag `--mode=universal` to the `build-apks` command in bundletool. It still generates an .apks file, but you can then extract the single .apk file from it (using unzip or bundletool's `extract-apks` command).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this command instead of generating new APK file.
This uses `bundletool` to install APKS file which generated from `bundletool build-apks`

> bundletool install-apks --apks=file-name.apks